# Are 'Primary Keys' obligatory in SQL Server Design?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design

Observe the following table model:

```
CREATE TABLE [site].[Permissions] (
    [ID]     INT REFERENCES [site].[Accounts]( [ID] ) NOT NULL,
    [Type]   SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
    [Value]  INT NULL
);
```

The site.Accounts->site.Permissions is a one-to-many relationship so 'ID' cannot be made a primary key due to the uniqueness that a PK imposes.

The rows are selected using a `WHERE [ID] = ?` clause, so adding a phoney IDENTITY column and making it the PK yields no benefit at the cost of additional disk space.

Its my understanding that the targeted platform - SQL Server (2008) - does not support composite PKs. These all add up to my question: **If a Primary Key is not used, so something wrong? Or could something be more right?**

Comment: This might be helpful reading: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/08/23/composite_primary_keys.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding is not correct, SQL Server does support composite primary keys!

The syntax to add one would be

```
ALTER TABLE  [site].[Permissions] 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Permissions PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id,[Type])
```

Regarding the question in the comments "What is the benefit of placing a PK on the entire table?"

I'm not sure from your description though what the PK would need to be on. Is it all 3 columns or just 2 of them? If it's on `id,[Type]` then presumably you wouldn't want the possibility that the same `id,[Type]`  combo could appear multiple times with conflicting values.

If it is on all 3 columns then to turn the question around why wouldn't you want a primary key?

If you are going to have a clustered index on your table you could just make that the primary key. If say you made a clustered index on the `id` column only SQL Server would add in uniqueifiers anyway to make it unique and your columns are so narrow (`int`,`smallint`,`int`) this just seems a pointless addition.

Additionally the query optimiser can use unique constraints to improve its query plans (though might not apply if the only queries on that table really are `WHERE [ID] = ?`) and it would be pretty wasteful to allow duplicates that you then have to both store and filter out with `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Okay... Surprised I couldn't find anything on google. Either way, what is the benefit of placing a PK on the entire table? 1. Data integrity: Identical rows are forbidden... 2.?

Comment: Entity integrity. I'm not sure from your description though what the PK would need to be on. Is it all 3 columns or just 2 of them? If it's on `id,[Type]` then presumably you wouldn't want the possibility that the same `id,[Type]` combo could appear with 2 different values. If it is on all 3 columns then it would just be wasteful to allow duplicates that you then have to both store and filter out with `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @Kivin: 2) Primary key generally means clustered index, which is better than a non-clustered one - especially considering how you will be searching the table.  The clustered key doesn't have to be the primary key, but generally it is.

Comment: @ Martin, you're right. When I sat down and read Michael Haren's link and went to work writing a PK, I realized that I only wanted the uniqueness on the first two columns.